# Clojure duplicate elements in sequence

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a simple sequence of arbitrary elements that I would like to reduce over two-by-two.

In order to do that, I generate pairs with the data, but the way I do it is wrong since I need to call a function generating the data twice :

```
(defn gen-pairs [l]
  (partition 2 (drop 1 (take l (interleave (gen-data) (gen-data))))))
```

How can I avoid calling `gen-data` twice (`gen-data` returns a sequence of items lazily, like `range` for instance) ?

Comment: One way would be to write your own version of `interleave` that took the `gen-data` function as its parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question would be clearer if you included an example of what output you wanted, but I *think* that you're after `partition` with a step of 1:

```
user=> (partition 2 1 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7])
((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (5 6) (6 7))
```